# Java Button action listener sets off other listener?

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener, jlabel

I've got two listeners within my Main class, labelButton listener changes the text in a JLabel, and the other colourButton changes the colour within a circle. For some reason, when I click labelButton, it sets off colourButton as well, but it only does this the first time it's clicked. I only want it to change the text in the JLabel!

```
public class Main {
    JFrame jframe;
    JLabel label;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
        labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener());

        JButton colourButton = new JButton("Change colours!");
        colourButton.addActionListener(new ColourListener());

        label = new JLabel("I'm a label");

        MyComponent component = new MyComponent();
        jframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colourButton);
        jframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, component);
        jframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
        jframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, label);

        jframe.setSize(400,400);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    class LabelListener implements ActionListener {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Ouch! " + i++);
        }
    }

    class ColourListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jframe.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Component

```
public class MyComponent extends JPanel{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        Color colour = new Color(red,green,blue);
        red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        Color endColour = new Color(red,green,blue);

        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,colour,150,150,endColour);

        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of the label, because it's transparent, will cause the parent container to be repainted, in order to remove any possibility of graphical artifacts.

Because the `paintComponent` method is randomising the colors, this means that any time it is repainted, the colors will change.

This is a good example of how you don't control the paint process and why your paint methods should only paint the CURRENT state of the component.

Remove the color randomisation to another method and call that from your `actionListener` which will also call `repaint` itself

Comment: there is possible to set, stop repainting

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not aware of any means by which you could prevent the parent component from been repainted in part or whole when a child component (especially one which is transparent) is changed...

Comment: @mKorbel Possibly, but then you'd end up with paint artifacts, as the transparent component would need the area beneath it to be updated, which would come out of sync with the rest of the component

Comment: `setIgnoreRepaint` should be used in active rendering only (fullscreen mode for example) which is not the case here. Modifying the drawing directly in the `paint` method is generally a bad way to do things, @MadProgrammer says it well: `paint` should only paint the current state not modify it.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a side effect of your label change.

When the label changes in length, components need to be relocated and a repaint is necessary. It suggest you not to change the color in the `paint` method but to change it in the action listener.